# Maven - Execute module class in parent

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven project like this:

- Parent

  - parentClass()
- Child

  - childClass ()

I want  invoke a child class which is in the child module from the parent module.

Thisare my poms:

**Parent:**

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test.test.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>parent</name>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>child-module</module>
    </modules>
```

**Child:**

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.test.test.child</groupId>
<artifactId>child-module</artifactId>

<name>child-module/name>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.test.test.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test.test.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I tried to invoke child class from a parent class.

```
public class ParentClass {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        Child child = new Child ();

    }       
 }
```

Comment: Child is unknown to the parent so not possible.  You must use another place that has both on the classpath.

Comment: The parent does not have any code nor will the code compiled etc. so you have to do a separate module for that purpose.